# HTML Email : Outlook put extra line middle of the email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am making HTML Emailer. when I see email in **Outlook** , it gives extra `hr` line in the middle of email.

I am having background as **#F5F5F5** , **#F1F1F1**. but When I put background as **#000000**, then there is no `hr` line in the email.

How can I solve it?

Any Help would be great. 
Thank You.

Comment: Please show some code where you are creating the e-mail.

Comment: `where are you` creating means? and code is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have given `border-color` of that line. so you might see `hr` line in your output.